# Why new instance is not in the instances list of load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

My EB environment uses laod balancer (min: 1, max: 4) and auto scaling group.
The auto scaling is triggered when CPU's Usage over 20%.

The auto scaling works well, new instance is automatically created when threshold is overed. But there is always a healthy check failure for the new created instance. I checked the load balancer related with my EB environment and found that the new created instance is not in the `instances` tab.I have to manually added the instance into `instances`. After manually adding the instance, the healthy check result becomes OK.

I would like to know if a config setting in EB environment can automatically add the newly created instance into the load balancers's instances list.

[image]

the config file for AWSEBLoadBalancer in .ebextensions is as:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBLoadBalancer:
    Properties:
      Listeners:
        - InstancePort: 80
          InstanceProtocol: HTTP
          LoadBalancerPort: 80
          Protocol: HTTP
      AccessLoggingPolicy:
        EmitInterval: 5
        Enabled: true
        S3BucketName:
          Ref: LogsBucket
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer"
    DependsOn: "LogsBucketPolicy" 
LogsBucket:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
...
```

Capacity configuration of environment is:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Go to EC2 console, and check there for LB and ASG settings. Maybe you need to increase `HealthCheckGracePeriod`?

Comment: @Marcin I increase the value, but doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add the code for EB creation/config?

Comment: @MuzaffarShaikh, thanks. I added config in the question.

Comment: @leilei Can you share your Autoscaling Group creation config?

Answer (score 0):

The autoscaling group configuration has a configuration option to specify the target group that instances are added to. Without that configuration, it would autoscale, but wouldn't add them to the target group and therefore you wouldn't see them in the load balancer either.

See this answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/1000783/application-load-balancer-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-target-group

"**So go to EC2 Console, then at the very bottom of the left menu (currently for me anyways) there's the Auto Scaling Groups. Click on the auto scaling group from the list, and on the Details tab, click Edit, and then add the applicable Target Group."**